# spring mongotemplate ISODate queries

Tags: mongodb-query, spring-data, mongotemplate

How can I create a query that uses ISODate instead of $date using mongotemplate ?
my property is of type ISODate and queries using $date fail, but I cant find a way to tell mongotemplate to generate the lte/gte queries using ISODate.

Comment: Can you add the sample code ? And what is your java and spring mongo version ?

Comment: it seems that updating to latest spring mongo fixed the issue, thanks